# Weird performance behavior

Tags: c#, performance, cil

So I have this 2 methods which suppose to multiply a 1000 items long array of integers by 2.
The first method:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
Power(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
    }
}
```

The second method:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
PowerNoLoop(int[] arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
    i++;
    arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
    i++;
    arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
    i++;
    ............1000 Times........
    arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
}
```

Note that I use this code only for performance research and that's why it looks so disgusting.

The surprising result is that `Power` is faster by almost 50% than `PowerNoLoop` even though I have checked the decompiled `IL` source of both of them and the content of the `for` loop is exactly the same as each line in `PowerNoLoop`.
How can it be?

Comment: How did you measure? Did you use release builds?

Comment: Tried both Debug and release. Tested with StopWatch over 200000 arrays of 1000 items

Comment: The second one probably won't benefit from CPU instruction cache?

Comment: Could you show IL code for both?

Comment: I would expect `arg[i] <<= 1` to be even faster.

Comment: I'll post the IL code later since im using stack exchange on phone. Ive used a local instead of 1000 consts since it uses ld.loc.0 instead of ldc.i4.s 0xXXX

Comment: You should post enough code to replicate your timing observations, if there is a problem with how you measure the time used we need to see that code.

Comment: Why did you disable optimizations? Seems like a pointless test.

Comment: Otherwise the `i` local variable in `PowerNoLoop` is replaced by consts and the IL code of the content of the loop will be different from the one of the second method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A sample measurement from my machine, running the test 10 times, `PowerNoLoop` is first:

```
00:00:00.0277138 00:00:00.0001553
00:00:00.0000142 00:00:00.0000057
00:00:00.0000106 00:00:00.0000053
00:00:00.0000084 00:00:00.0000053
00:00:00.0000080 00:00:00.0000053
00:00:00.0000075 00:00:00.0000053
00:00:00.0000080 00:00:00.0000057
00:00:00.0000080 00:00:00.0000053
00:00:00.0000080 00:00:00.0000053
00:00:00.0000075 00:00:00.0000053
```

Yes, about 50% slower.  Notable is the jitter overhead in the first pass through the test, obviously it burns a lot more core trying to get that huge method compiled. Keep in mind that the measurement is vastly different when you don't disable the optimizer, the no-loop version is then ~800% slower.

First place to always look for an explanation is the generated machine code, you can see it with Debug > Windows > Disassembly. The primary troublespot is the prologue of the `PowerNoLoop()` method. Looks like this in x86 code:

```
067E0048  push        ebp                       ; setup stack frame
067E0049  mov         ebp,esp  
067E004B  push        edi                       ; preserve registers
067E004C  push        esi  
067E004D  sub         esp,0FA8h                 ; stack frame size = 4008 bytes  
067E0053  mov         esi,ecx  
067E0055  lea         edi,[ebp-0ACCh]           ; temp2 variables
067E005B  mov         ecx,2B1h                  ; initialize 2756 bytes
067E0060  xor         eax,eax                   ; set them to 0
067E0062  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]
```

Note the very large stack size, 4008 bytes.  Far too much for a method with only one local variable, it should only require 8 bytes.  The extra 4000 of them are temporary variables, I named them `temp2`.  They are initialized to 0 by the `rep stos` instruction, that takes a while.  I can't explain 2756.

The individual adds are a very plodding affair in the non-optimized code.  I'll spare you the machine code dump and write it in equivalent C# code:

```
if (i >= arr.Length) goto throwOutOfBoundsException
var temp1 = arr[i];
if (i >= arr.Length) goto throwOutOfBoundsException
var temp2 = temp1 + arr[i];
if (i >= arr.Length) goto throwOutOfBoundsException
arr[i] = temp2
```

Repeated over and over again, a thousand times total.  The `temp2` variable is the troublemaker, there's one each for each individual statement.  Thus adding 4000 bytes to the stack frame size.  If anybody has a guess at 2756 then I'd love to hear it in a comment.

Having to set them all to 0 before the method can start running is, roughly, what produces the 50% slow-down.  There is probably some instruction fetch and decode overhead as well, it can't be isolated easily from the measurement.

Notable as well is that they are *not* eliminated when you remove the [MethodImpl] attribute and allow the optimizer to do its job.  The method is in fact not optimized at all, surely because it doesn't want to tackle such a large chunk of code.

---

Conclusion you should draw is to always leave it up to the jitter optimizer to unroll loops for you.  It knows better.

Comment: That conclusion is false given the state of the 3 JITs that we have today.

Comment: Oh, you hopeless cynic.  Loop unrolling is not a slamdunk optimization anymore today, the instruction decoder is getting to be a pretty significant bottleneck.  Getting the x86 jitter modernized for current micro-architectures is not in the cards.

Comment: :) What I want is a super fast first tier JIT or interpreter and a high-quality second tier JIT. Should reduce .NET startup times as well. Not sure why they are not doing it. Java seems to like it. How expensive can it be to write an interpreter for IL?! This path seems even cheaper to build than rewriting the JIT. Write an interpreter and plug in MSVC or LLVM as the second tier JIT. The latter is actually being done right now.

Comment: Hmm, that's not going to cost much, given that they already have one.  Used in .NET Micro.  I'll have to leave "super fast interpreter" to the imagination.  If you like the JVM then just use Java, I'm not hearing a lot of ".NET jitters suck" putdowns coming from that corner however.

Comment: "super fast interpreter" = no initialization cost, low throughput.; To Java people .NET does not even exist. That's cultural. They are debating language design issues that C# has solved 5 years ago because they don't take note that C# has done that. I'm sure the same is true for the JIT with the addition that the .NET JIT is really pointless to look at. From what I have seen the Hotspot JIT is fantastic. It's great at removing abstraction cost stemming from managed languages. Tiered JIT, vcalls go away, range checks are rare, objects allocated on the stack, ...

Comment: I am not convinced by "mov  ecx,2B1h ; initialize 2756 bytes",  I **think** it is JUST writing a value into ecx.

Comment: @IanRingrose, it is indeed writing a plain value to the 'ECX' register, that is however used later on by the 'rep stos' instruction as a counter of how many double words to write - starting at  the address stored in the 'es:edi' register. You should view Hans's remarks as a multi-line comment explaining the purpose of the last three instructions, as a whole   =)

Comment: @IanRingrose, sorry, from reading your answer below, I guess that you understood the purpose of the disassembled code in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Because the c# jit compiler is optimized to eliminate bounds checks if it can deduce that the variable will not go outside the range of the for loop.

The case with the `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)` is caught by the optimizer, the other case not.

Here is a blog post about it, it's long but worth the read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx

Comment: IIRC Bounds checking are not eliminated by the c# compiler it is done by the JIT compiler. (Btw I've not read the article yet). Here JIT can't optimize the code as we're using `MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization`. So this doesn't seems to be the case for me.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You're right, it is the JIT compiler.

Comment: But wait. JIT can't optimize both the methods here `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` says the JIT to *Shut up, Don't optimize my code*. So it is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Depends if this option is configurable :)

Comment: According to just the [official MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx), Sriram is quite right. Unless OP uses his own attribute there is no JIT optimization done here.

Comment: I Just checked in visual studio 2008 (yes, i know it's old), and the bounds checks are eliminated, even with that property on the function.

Comment: @BastiM This is not my own attribute :)

Answer (score 2):

Hans Passant seems to have hit the main issues on the head, but has missed some points.

Firstly as Mark Jansen says, the code generator (in the JIT) has a special case to remove bonds checking for simple array access in simple for loops.    It is very likely that `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]`  does not effect this.   Your unrolled loop has to do this check 3000 times!

The next issue is that it takes much longer to read data (or code) from memory then it does to run an instruction that is already in the processor 1st level cache.     There is also limited bandwidth from the CPU to RAM, so whenever the CPU is reading an instruction from memory, it can’t be reading from (or updating) the array.   Once the loop in `Power` has executed the first time, all processor instructions will be in the 1st level cache – they may even be stored in a partly decoded form.

Updating 1000 different `tempN` variables, will put load on the CPU cache and maybe even RAM (as the CPU does not know they are not going to be read again, so must save them to RAM)      (Without `MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization`, the JIT may combine the `tempN` variables into a few variables that will then fit in registers.)

These days most CPUs can run many instructions at the same time ([Superscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar)), therefore it is very likely that all the loop checks (1 < arr.Length) etc  are being executed at the same time as the store/load from the array.  Even the conditional GoTo at the end of the loop with be hidden by [Speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) (and/or [Out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)).

**Any reasonable CPU will be able to run your loop in about the time it takes to read/write the value from memory.**

If you had done the same test on 20 years ago on a PC then it is likely you would have got the result you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing these results in my tests. I suspect that your tests may be being distorted by garbage collection.

My test results for a release build are as follows (using Visual Studio 2015, .Net 4.6, Windows 10):

x64:

```
Power() took 00:00:01.5277909
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:01.4462461
Power() took 00:00:01.5403739
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:01.4038312
Power() took 00:00:01.5327902
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:01.4318121
Power() took 00:00:01.5451933
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:01.4252743
```

x86:

```
Power() took 00:00:01.1769501
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:00.9933677
Power() took 00:00:01.1557201
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:01.0033348
Power() took 00:00:01.1119558
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:00.9588702
Power() took 00:00:01.1167853
PowerNoLoop() took 00:00:00.9553292
```

And the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            int count = 200000;
            var test = new int[1000];

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    Power(test);

                Console.WriteLine("Power() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    PowerNoLoop(test);

                Console.WriteLine("PowerNoLoop() took " + sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
        public static void Power(int[] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
            }
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
        public static void PowerNoLoop(int[] arr)
        {
            int i = 0;
            arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i];
            ++i;
            <snip> Previous two lines repeated 1000 times.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copied and pasted your code and my results are as wierd as before. I use .NET 4.5.2

Comment: @Some1Pr0 Be interesting to see what results other people get.